# Maximum matrix size in Scala Breeze or other Java/Scala matrix packages?

Tags: scala-breeze

I am trying to write a generic modelling code in Scala that relies on a grid (matrix or tensor). After much looking around, I decided to use Breeze for the matrix because (1) it's API is in Scala, which is nice, (2) it is reasonably fast for what I need (not a lot of linear algebra, more a convenient data structure), and (3) it allows me to store non-Primitive values and saves their types (not everything is a Numerical value in my application).

However, I cannot find an information about maximum matrix size. I managed to blow my heap size a few times by creating large tensors (matrix of 100'000 x 10'000 cells each containing a Vector of dimension 5), but I managed to overcome this by increasing my heap size.

Now the above matrix works, but I get an 'interesting' error though when I try to create a matrix of 100'000 x 100'000 cells each containing a Vector of dimension 5. This is what it gives me:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1410065408 out of bounds for length 1410065408

I suspect it has to do with the internals of how Breeze works with indexes, but I am not sure. I don't really mind having a limit in size (this is life) but I would need to know it to catch this before it crashes the application. Anyone has an idea?

Or is there a better package out there for what I need? I played with OjAlgo, which is nice but slower at creating the matrix than Breeze and can only store boxed primitives or primitives, not objects. Maybe Spark?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Breeze's DenseMatrix representation is backed by a single Java array, so the total number of elements is capped at (a little less than) 2^31.